# What class in Spring is responsible for resolving messages in a view

Tags: java, spring, view, thymeleaf

I am writing a spring mvc app with a use case of custom messages (labels) per each client.  Each request will have a unique key in the path like:

```
http://somehost/something/A1B2C3D4/page
http://somehost/something/H7CD8E31/page
```

Based off the key I will load custom messages from a database.

I found an article that uses custom database messages for the whole app here:
[Custom Database messages](http://blog.mornati.net/spring-mvc-database-messagesource-fall-back-to-properties-file/)

I modified this approach a bit and read the request using the following code:

```
    private String getIdFromRequest() {

    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest req = attr.getRequest();

    String id=null;
    try {
        id = ((String) req.getServletPath()).split("/")[1];
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Request did not have key");
    }

    return id;
}
```

I then call this message inside `resolveCode` of my class that extends `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

If a page has 20 messages then this block of code is run 20 times per page. My question is where or how does spring read the messages from the view template? When rendering a view, it resolves the view to a file, then it must loop over the messages calling `resolveCode` on each one. I wanted to call my `getIdFromRequest` method once per page by extended the class where the looping takes place. I was looking through the spring source code but I can not find what I am looking for yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also if there is a better way to solve my issue I would appreciate some direction on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You did not spoke of thymeleaf in your question, but as it is in the tags, I assume you are using it.

If it is the case, as thymeleaf is a template library, all is done at view rendering. I think that the relevant class is not a spring class but a thymeleaf one.

I advice you to look in `org.thymeleaf.spring3.view` which is the view you are using in your application. If you want to use a specialized subclass, you should probaly first subclass the `ViewResolver` from same package.

If you do not use thymeleaf, the general workflow is the same : you have a `ViewResolver` declared in spring context. The `ViewResolver` instantiate a `View` and all the actual building of the response occurs in the `View`.